# Tile placement algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, block, tile

I have this field of tiles which is 36 x 36 inches wide and high.

[image: 36 x 36]

So I have blocks 8x8, 6x6, 6x8, 4x8 which can be rotated 90 degrees to fit wherever possible.
My task is to make application that calulates which and how many blocks should be chosen so that all together fit in to a given wall oppening. In this example oppening 36 x 36.

Note: The oppening should be filled with as least as possible tiles, meaning bigger tiles have priority

Which algorithm should I use for tile placement?

Another example. Field 30 x 30 is drawn like this:

[image: 30 x 30]

50 x 50

[image: 50 x 50]

Comment: Do you have some specified number of blocks of each type, or an unlimited number of each?

Comment: unlimited number of blocks. This is just placing glass blocks into a wall openning. The software should determine the cheapest way to place blocks i.e less blocks is better but still to fill the whole oppening.

Comment: I have a software which does this but I don't have acess to the source code so I have to rework it into another application from scratch

Comment: yes it could be knapsack problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: I will be busy these days. I have to analyze what I have so far so I will need time.

Comment: I have to check with the client. It will happen soon. Good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since amit gave the [general case answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21482434/752320), I'll make this one specific. With those four blocks sizes, and assuming it's even possible (dimensions are even and >= 6, etc), you can use a semi-greedy algorithm:

The first obective is to maximize the number of 8x8 blocks. To do that, you need to figure out how many `6` size blocks you need in each direction. For each dimension, just check for divisibility by 8. If it's not divisible, subtract 6. Repeat until divisible (it shouldn't take more than 3 tries).

However many times it took, that's how may 6x6 blocks you need in that dimension. Form a rectangle out of them and put it in one corner. Form another rectangle out of 8x8 blocks and put them in the opposite corner. The corners of these two rectangles should be touching.

So now you probably have some leftover space, in the form of two rectangles in the opposite corners. We know that one dimension of each is divisible by 8, and one is divisible by 6. The easy way out here would be to fill it up with 6x8 blocks rotated appropriately, but that doesn't *guarantee* the maximum number of large(8x8) blocks. For example, with 50x50, you'd have two rectangles of 18x32 left. You *could* fill them with twelve 6x8 tiles each. You can't even *do* better than 12 blocks each, but you *can* fit more 8x8 blocks in there.

If that's not a concern, then you're done (hooray). The bonus this way is that you never need to use the 4x8 blocks.

---

If you *do* want to maximize the 8x8 blocks, you'll have to take another step. We're concentrating on the dimension divisible by 6 here, because the 8 is easy. Every size we might need(8x8,6x8,4x8) stacks there perfectly.

For the other side, there are only 3 possible numbers that it could be: 6, 12, and 18. If it's anything else, the first step wasn't done right. Then take the following action:

- For 6, add a row of 6x8 (no optimization)
- For 12, add a row of 4x8 and a row of 8x8
- For 18, add a row of 4x8, a row of 6x8, a row of 8x8

Done!

---

To see the difference, here we have two 50x50 grids:

```
Blue  - 8x8
Red   - 6x6
Green - 6x8
Gray  - 4x8
```

[image: basic]

This first example gives us 49 total blocks. The blue is a 32x32 area (16 blocks), red is 18x18 (9 blocks), and the rest is simply filled with 6x8's (24 blocks).

[image: better]

This example still gives 49 total, but there are more 8x8 blocks. Here we have 24 large blocks, rather than 16 in the last example. There are now also 4x8 blocks being used.

Comment: Are you sure that maximizing 8x8 blocks is the right call? I suspect there might be cases where using fewer 8x8 blocks might then leave behind a space that can be tiled with fewer smaller blocks than would be required if 8x8 blocks were used.

Comment: @templatetypedef I was skeptical at first, so I tested it with each even dimension between 24 and 48. Any other size should be similar, since 24 is the LCM of 6 and 8. I couldn't find a better solution with any size. I'd be interested in any counterexamples you can come up with.

Comment: Note that the first method(example 1) comes up with the same solution as pentadecagon's code example, the only difference is how you get there. For the second example, the only time anything changes is when you add a row of 4x8 blocks. Then you're simply swapping a 4x8 and 8x8 for two 6x8's, which doesn't change the total number of tiles.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, in Python:

```
def aux(x):
    # in h we store the pre-calculated results for small dimensions
    h = {18:[6,6,6], 16:[8,8], 14:[8,6], 12:[6,6], 10:[6,4], 8:[8], 6:[6], 4:[4]}
    res = []
    while x > 18: 
        # as long as the remaining space is large, we put there tiles of size 8
        res.append(8)
        x -= 8
    if x not in h:
        print("no solution found")
        return []

    return res + h[x]

def tiles( x, y ):
    ax = aux(x) # split the x-dimension into tiles
    ay = aux(y) # split the y-dimension into tiles
    res = [ [ (x,y) for x in ax ] for y in ay ]
    for u in res:
        print(u)
    return res


tiles( 30, 30 )
```

The basic idea is that you can solve x and y independently, and then combine the two solutions.

**Edit:** As Dukeling says this code happily uses 4x6 and 4x4 blocks, contrary to the requirements.  However, I think it does that only if there is no other way.  So if the results contains such blocks then there is no solution without those blocks.  And if you have no Python readily available, you can play with this code here: http://ideone.com/HHB7F8 , just press *fork* right above the source code.

Comment: Are you assuming there's a 4x4 block (my Python is rusty)? (And it's generally not a good idea to post (non-pseudo) code without much explanation to non-language-specific questions)

Comment: Right. Thanks.  I added some more text.  If there is an policy that pseudo-code is to be preferred I will of course happily adapt.  I just think there is an advantage if you can run the code right away.

Comment: (No policy) It's certainly advantageous to have actual code in an answer, but you could post pseudo-code / a high-level description along with it, or just link to a live demo of the code. The disadvantage of only actual code is that it could be unreadable to anyone not familiar with the language, and, if the question doesn't have that language tag, it's likely that lots of such people will read your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for general case answer, I am sorry to say - but this problem is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete). It is basically a 2D variation of the [Subset Sum Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

The subset sum problem: Given a set `S` and a number `x` - find out if there is a subset of `S` that sums to `x`.

It is easy to see that by reducing the subset sum problem to a "field" of size `1*x` and for every `s` in `S` we have a tile `1*s` - a solution to one problem is also a solution to the other one.

Thus - there is no known polynomial solution to this problem, and most believe one does not exist.

Note however, there is a [pseudo-polynomial dynamic programming solution to subset sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution) that might be utilized here as well.

Comment: Well in this case, it seems like the solution sought is not the general one, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: How do you change that algorithm to make it solve the 2D variant?

Comment: @harold I am not sure yet, but I think by increasing the dimensionality of the problem, and by dividing each problem to subproblems according to the new (2) rectangles created by placing a tile. Not sure exactly how yet, this is why I only give a pointer to this solution and indicated it *might* be utilized.

Comment: Being NP-complete doesn't mean it's not feasible. It's all a matter of the size of the problem. Now 8x8 can blocks can be skipped because they're expressed as two adjacent 4x8 blocks (in 2 ways). So, after 90deg. rotations we're left with 6x6, 6x8, 8x6, 4x8, 8x4. Which may not be that much...

Comment: @valdo I agree, I was refering to the *general case* of the problem. Obviously it is easy to solve a small NP-Complete problem (TSP with 8 cities, for example)

Comment: Given that the blocks are all a small integer multiple of 2 units in each dimension, I think it would be quite a stretch to call this NP-complete. With a fixed, finite set of sizes, "pseudo-polynomial" isn't  really pseudo-.